# How would I convert this javascript to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, type-conversion

```
function loaded() {
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
    myScroll = new iScroll('scroller');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded);
```

If its possible... 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    var blah = new iScroll('scroller');
});
```

i believe this would work.

Comment: What about this part?

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded);